# How to get the hex color code from a color dialog in visual studio?

Tags: c#, colors, visual-studio-2015, hex, color-picker

I have a color dialog in visual studio, I am currently using this c# code to display the color dialog and set the color to a panel:

```
private void ColorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ColorPanel.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
    }
}
```

How could I set a label to the hexadecimal color code of the color picker?

Comment: Beat me to it by 1 second...

Comment: ColorTranslator.ToHtml(colorDialog1.Color);

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this

1. Get `ARGB` (Alpha, Red, Green, Blue) representation for the color
2. Filter out *Alpha* channel: `& 0x00FFFFFF`
3. Format out the value as hexadecimal (`"X6"`)

Implementation

```
  String code = (colorDialog1.Color.ToArgb() & 0x00FFFFFF).ToString("X6");
```

**Edit**: if you want to get `Color` *back* from `code`, try `FromArgb`:

```
  string code = "FFDDAA";

  Color color = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(code, 16));
```

Comment: You should post that answer in the duplikate marked answer aswell

Comment: @fubo: I see, thank you! I've posted (adapted) answer to the duplicate question as well.

Comment: Anyone know how to reverse this? To go from HEX to Color?

Comment: @Mark: try `Color.FromArgb` and `Convert.ToInt32` (see my edit)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Couldn't get that to work. `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");` was what I ended up using.